# Set Column Of Data In Google Sheets To PDF Sharable Links From A Google Drive Folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I am trying to set a column of data to the URL of a sharable link from a folder in google drive. I need to export a sheet to a .csv to upload to a CRM and need to attach a file to each customer being created. This is my current script, but I do not believe that it is setting the data value to the row correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function setSharableLink() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var folderId = "1vpdKVsvOt5ZkMdreJm29jSMgghf1ydpD";
    var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
    var result = [];
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
      var temp = {
        file_name: file.getName(),
        url: "http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + file.getId(),
      };
      row[2] = temp;
      result.push(temp);  
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you the detail information about `I do not believe that it is setting the data value to the row correctly.`?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to append the content of `row[2]` to `url`?